# Is there a Lightbox style plugin that fits images to screen size?

Tags: javascript, looking-for-a-script, jquery, responsive-webdesign

I'm looking for a Lightbox type js plugin that would take into account the browser window size and resize the currently displayed photo so it fits - like the [jquery-imagefit](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-imagefit-plugin/) plugin does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly standard feature, at least among the well-known options. (To the point that they generally don't bother making too much mention of it.) It doesn't seem like it'd be hard to find one unless you're looking for something more. Anyway:

- [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/options.html), with the handleOversize argument
- [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), with the fitToView argument
- [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) takes a different approach with its scalePhotos argument.

(BTW: The demos for the scripts above don't load huge images into the overlays, so to see the effect, reduce your browser window to 800x600 or something.)

Comment: _To the point that they generally don't bother making too much mention of it._

Thank you, now it makes sense why googling didn't help at all :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a WordPress plugin that handles this named FooBox. It can be found at http://getfoobox.com